# Eliminating variables in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am brand new to Mathematica, and want to eliminate one variable, iNt from a system of two equations, which should result is a fourth oder ODE for the remaining variable Nprime.  Here is what I have tried:

```
mass1=hBar*nPrime''[x]+\[Sigma]^2*(nPrime[x] - iNt[x])==nBar[x] 
mass2=(h-hBar)*(nPrime''[x]+\[Rho]*iNt''[x])+\[Sigma]^2*iNt[x]== 0
Eliminate[{mass1, mass2}, iNt]
```

The answer consists of two equation and iNt has not been eliminated:

```
nBar[x] == -\[Sigma]^2 iNt[x] + \[Sigma]^2 nPrime[x] + hBar (nPrime^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] && h (\[Rho] (iNt^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] + (nPrime^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]) == -\[Sigma]^2 iNt[x] + hBar \[Rho] (iNt^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] + hBar (nPrime^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Eliminate` only works on plain variables, not functions.  This may be what you want, first replace the function `iNt[x]` with a symbol and eliminate that.

```
Eliminate[{
   mass1 = 
    hBar*nPrime''[x] + \[Sigma]^2*(nPrime[x] - iNt[x]) == nBar[x],
   mass2 = (h - hBar)*(nPrime''[x] + \[Rho]*iNt''[x]) + \[Sigma]^2*
       iNt[x] == 0
   } /. iNt[x] -> aa, aa]
```

> [Sigma]^2 nPrime[x] + h [Rho] (iNt^[Prime][Prime])[x] - 
>     hBar [Rho] (iNt^[Prime][Prime])[x] + 
>     h (nPrime^[Prime][Prime])[x] == nBar[x]

Here the second derivative of `iNt` remains. Is that what you want?

Eliminating the function takes a bit more hand work:

```
 iNt[x_] = iNt[x] /. Solve[mass1, iNt[x]][[1, 1]]
 mass2
```

> fourth order equation in `nPrime`

Comment: Thanks so much and no, I want to eliminate iNt completely and be left with a fourth order equn with nPrime as the only dependent variable.  BTW nBar[x] is (known) forcing

Comment: Great, that does the trick!!  Can I ask what the set set of square brackets [[1,1]] does?

Comment: `Solve` returns a list of solutions, so `[[1,1]]` takes first solution, first variable. (just `[[1]]` is all you really need here)